# Error when Registering User with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class DriverRegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
    private Button mRegistration, mLogin;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_registration);

        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mRegistration = findViewById(R.id.registration);
        mLogin = findViewById(R.id.login);

        mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(DriverRegistrationActivity.this, DriverLoginActivity.class));
            }
        });

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(DriverRegistrationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if ( !task.isSuccessful() ) {
                            Toast.makeText(DriverRegistrationActivity.this, "Registration Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Riders").child(user_id);
                            current_user_db.setValue(true);
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the toast I've set for an error. The user isn't being created in my Firebase database. In emulators, it says "App won't run unless you update google play services"

I have a realtime database set up with a child "Users" and a child under that "Riders"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the emulator's google play services version first update the google play services and then try to run the app

open this url from your device to update google play services
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en_IN